# Call Javascript function onClick in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I understand the scoping rules and what is normally allowed in the chrome console, but I'm curious if there is a way to have a button or link logged to the console, that when clicked will run a function.

The intent is that I can return to a specific state in my web app, which logs whenever the state has been changed (similar to redux's chrome extension).

[image]

I know I can bind functions to the window object, and I know I can just type in the function name to make the call. What I'm interested in doing is having a button or Link so that I don't have to type it out, and I can just click in the console where I want to restore the state.

Comment: Could you please show an example of what you want? If you want the console itself changed, you will probably need to create a Chrome extension for it (or find an existing one). If you need a button on the page, you can create a UserScript that will add a button to the page and use TamperMonkey to install it.

Comment: You cannot do this natively in the devs console. So you have to write an userscript or an extension which adds a button to the page and interacts with the script. If you don't want to see this, you can introduce a sorta "debug" mode (global variable) which - if turned "on" - puts the states in an array and use a dummy function eg `res(5)` to restore to state 5 in the array. These implementations can be removed automatically when you're minifying your script.